# OpenCL: how lightweight are GPU threads?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I keep reading that GPU threads are lightweight and you can throw many tasks at them to complete in parallel....but how lightweight are they, exactly?

Let's say I have a million-member float3 array, and I want to calculate the length of each float3 value.

Does it make sense to send essentially 1 million tasks to the GPU (so the kernel calculates a single float3 length of the global array and returns)? Or something more like 1000 tasks, and each kernel execution loops through 1000 members of the array? If there is a benefit to grouping tasks like that, is there a way to calculate the optimal size of each grouping?

Comment: This is one of the issues with open cl, the only way to find out is to run your task with various different group sizes on your gpu and find out what is the optimal size, there is no general answer to what is the best task size

Comment: I can't speak toward OpenCL specifically, but in CUDA, a recurring theme is that for many kinds of problems, you'll be limited by your GPU's memory bandwidth long before you get close to the theoretical maximum performance. This problem sounds like it will be memory-bound, not compute-bound, so I would emphasize experimenting with different memory access patterns to see what gets you the highest throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about GPUs only, the answer is - very lightweight.

> Does it make sense to send essentially 1 million tasks to the GPU

You're not "sending a million tasks" to the GPU. You're sending a single request, which is a few dozen bytes, which essentially says "please launch a million copies of this code with the grid coordinates i give you here". Those "copies" are created on the fly by hardware inside the GPU, and yes it's very efficient.

> 1000 tasks, and each kernel execution loops through 1000 members of the array

On a GPU, you almost certainly don't want to do this. A modern high-end GPU has easily 4000+ processing units, so you need *at minimum* that amount of concurrency. But usually much higher. There is a scheduler which picks one hardware thread to run on each of those processing units, and usually there are several dozen hardware threads per processing unit. So it's not unusual to see a GPU with 100K+ hardware threads. This is required to hide memory latencies.

So if you launch a kernel with 1000x1 grid size, easily 3/4 of your GPU could be unused, and the used part will spend 90% of it's time waiting for memory. Go ahead and try it out. The GPU has been *designed* to handle ridiculous amounts of threads - don't be afraid to use them.

Now, if you're talking about CPU, that's a slightly different matter. CPUs obviously don't have 1000s of hardware threads. Here, it depends on the OpenCL implementation - but i think most reasonable CPU OpenCL implementations today will handle this for you, by processing work in loops, in just enough hardware threads for your CPU.

TL;DR: use the "1 million tasks" solution, and perhaps try tuning the local work size.